# Find radius of convergence for power series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I am working through the exercises of Conway's "Functions of One Complex Variable." In Chaper III, Section 1, Exercise 6, we are asked to find the radius of convergence for the following power series:
\begin{equation}
\text{(a)}\qquad \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a^n z^n, \quad a\in \mathbb{C}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\text{(c)}\qquad \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} k^n z^n, \quad \text{k an integer }\neq 0.
\end{equation}
For part (a), I found the radius of convergence $1/|a|$. Part (c) seems to be a special case, but in that case the exercise doesn't make much sense to me. Am I missing something? Or is there a typo?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are right, there is maybe a typo.

Comment: Look at the errata here: https://www.math.tamu.edu/~boas/courses/617-2018c/errata.shtml.

Comment: Ok cool, thank you for your confirmation! I just wanted to make sure, I didn't miss anything.